# Tooltip does not appear

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display the tooltip when you hover over the marker, as the following image:
https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/811258/632902/b958437e-d1ee-11e2-9c2b-2c3b76d6b95a.png

But I can not get it to work properly:
http://bit.ly/1byCIDn

I am using the following fork of ChartJS:
https://github.com/jhdavids8/Chart.js

Comment: Whenever I try to getElementById("tooltip"), it returns null.

Comment: Where you have defined values variable / array? And have you put given html in your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your chart.js file in that there is no tooltip option

download chart.js file from the link 
https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.js/tree/tooltips